# How to perform a simple DOM-based XSS attack

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss

Here's my index.html (vulnerable):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<script>
    document.write("<form><select>"); 

    document.write("<option value=1>" + 
    document.location.href.substring(document.location.href.indexOf("default=") + 8)
+ "</option>");

    document.write("<option value=2> French </option>");

    document.write("</select> </form>");
    document.write(document.location.href);
</script>
  <body>

  </body>

</html>
```

It supposed to get default language from `../index.html?default=English` which will set the default language into English.

I'm trying to use `../index.html?default=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>` to show the cookie on the screen, but the browser seems to encode `>` into `%3E`. I have also used `\x3Cscript>alert(document.cookie)\x3C/script>`, `\x3Cscript\3Ealert(document.cookie)\x3C/script\3E and &lt;script&gt;alert(document.cookie)&lt;/script&gt;`, but no luck.

Comment: have you tried sending a direct get request to that page via console?

Comment: I've reformatted your code and [also made a plunkr out of it](http://run.plnkr.co/gnLT3AT8nw3Ozm26/?default=English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vulnerable code needs to use `decodeURIComponent` on the string parsed out of the location, for the attack to work:

```
document.write("<option value=1>" + 
    decodeURIComponent(
        document.location.href.substring(
            document.location.href.indexOf("default=") + 8)) 
    + "</option>");
```

It would "make sense" (for somebody writing vulnerable code...) to do that because the string coming from the URL may legitimately contain characters such as `>`.

For a demo see http://plnkr.co/edit/Vctoj7GOLMvlvhS98Mk4?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your response. It makes sense for someone to write that code according to your explanation.